# Python: check regex expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I generate my own regex expression and I would like to check if it is valid. For example if I have regex "[a-zA-Z0-9]" it will be valid but "[a-zA-Z0s-9]" not.

Comment: Using `re.compile()`?  You could do that in a `try`/`except` block (and catch `re.error`).

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "generate my own regex"?  Are you *dynamically* generating regexes?

Comment: Yes... I generate own regexes according to some pattern. But sometimes it makes mistakes, so I want to catch that a generate my warning to stderr with exit code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if regex is valid from inside python:

```
import re
re.compile('<regex>')
```

This code will throw an error if it's invalid regex.

However, I find it much more useful to use regex tool, here's a few to choose from:

- [regexr](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: I want to catch invalid regex a generate my warning to stderr with exit code.

Comment: solved. thank you for help and hint! :)

Comment: You'll just need to surround it in a try except :)